# Bulk insert records into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a text file that contains about a million records. What is the best way to insert them into a SQL Server database from C#?

Can I use `BULK INSERT`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best way is to use the [`bcp` utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) or an [SSIS workflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx). Those tools have refinements like caching and batching your will miss in a naive implementation. Next best option is [`BULK INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) statement, as long as the SQL Server engine itself can reach the file. Last option would be [`SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class which allows your app do read the file, maybe process it and transform it, then feed the data as an enumerator to the SqlBulkCopy.

Comment: I have used SqlBulkCopy but the question is how can i know the total Rows inserted using SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer() function ??

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you put `SqlBulkCopy` behind the other options?

Answer (score 1):

I recently worked on same kind of problem , i realized there are couple solutions to it.

I wrote a BatchProgram (for batch program design read this -  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164014.aspx)

You can use SQL Server Utilities either BCP.exe  or OSQL.exe or .net framework supplied SQLBulkCopy class.

I ended up using BCP ( i got a CSV file and used a formatting file and load the data) and OSQL ( i used OSQL where i have to supply a file to the the stored proc )

i also went to .NET Process class and used outputdatarecieved event to log all output of BCP.exe into console (Read this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx) this worked pretty well.

I also tried to SQLBulkCopy class , but it can be slow if you load data first to datatable ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x.aspx ) , if you use IDataReader ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/434atets.aspx ) it could be fast .

Since i had millions rows i tried using  CSVReader ( http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader )  which is pretty fast .But down the line there was too much problem in data conversion and i did not have much flexibity in SQL server side .

I ended up using BCP and OSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Is using C# a requirement? The fastest way is to use the bcp command line tool: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

Comment: Thanks Chris Shain, I want to use c# because this will be a part of an application written with C#