# Table valued parameters with reference to other tables

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have been trying to figure out how to efficiently insert 100000 rows at a time from C# console program to sql server DB.

1. Select 100000 from input table
2. Send each record to an API.
3. Results are collected in a List Object
4. call a procedure that takes table valued parameter.
5. I cannot directly say Insert into empaddr_verified select * from @EMPObj parameter because the verified_table is referencing other tables.

What is the best way to handle this?

```
 create table #input_table(empid [varchar] (10) not null,
empaddr  [varchar](2000) NULL,[EMpName] [varchar](1000) NULL))
insert into  empaddr_tobeverified('1','1 main st, salem,pa,USA','JOE STILTON');
insert into  empaddr_tobeverified('2','200 Baker st, salem,pa,USA','JIMMY WU');

create table Addrstatus(
statusid [int] IDENTITY(1,1) not null primary key,
statusDesc  [varchar](2000) not NULL);
insert into Addrstatus(1,'OK');
insert into Addrstatus(2,'Not OK');

create table empaddr_verified(
empid [varchar] (10) not null primary key,
empalladdr  [varchar](2000) NULL,[EMpName] [varchar](1000) NULL,
statusid int not null Foreign Key references Addrstatus(statusid))
insert into empaddr_verified(
    '1'
    ,'1 main st, salem,pa,USA | 100 WHITE Terr, Acton,MA USA'
    ,'JOE STILTON'
    ,(If not exists(
        select statusid 
        from AddrStatus where statusDesc='NOT VERy SURE') 
        INSERT INTO Addrstatus('NOT VERy SURE'))))


create table employeeaddress(empid Foreign key references empaddr_verified(empid), empaddr varchar(1000) not null)l
insert into employeeaddresses('1','1 main st, salem,pa,USA ')
insert into employeeaddresses('1','100 WHITE Terr, Acton,MA USA ');

CREATE TYPE [testdb].[EMPTBL] AS TABLE(
    [EMpName] [varchar](1000) NULL,
               [EMpAllAddr] [varchar](1000) NULL,
               [EMpID] [varchar](10) not NULL) , statusDesc varchar2(100) not null

create procedure usp_test
(@EMPObj As [testdb].[EMPTBL] Readonly)
insert into empaddr_verified as select * from @EMPObj
```

-- works when status id is in AddrStatus table
-- not sure how to handle when StatusID does not exist in AddrStatus table & how to do it with table valued parameters

Comment: Surely you'd only have a limited number of known AddressStatuses? (1,'OK') and (2,'Not OK') (+ maybe a few more) So why would you insert anything other than 1 or 2 into the statusid column of empaddr_verified?

Comment: @JamesS, There can be more AddressStatus other than (1,'OK') and (2,'Not OK'). This AddressStatus is from an API and we have to store it.

Comment: ok, fair enough. Does your API take one address at a time, or does it take a whole batch? If its a one-at-a-time API I suspect its going to be the bottleneck far more so than individual insert statements anyway

Comment: @JamesS, it takes one address at a time :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the bottleneck is likely to be your API rather than the speed of individual inserts I'd stop worrying about a bulk insert.

Instead you do just create a stored procedure something like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EmpAddressSetStatus
  @empid INT,
  @statusValue NVARCHAR(2000)
AS

-- see if there is an existing status
DECLARE @statusId INT
SELECT @statusId =  statusId FROM AddrStatus WHERE statusDesc=@statusValue

-- if not then insert the new status
IF @statusId IS NULL 
BEGIN
  INSERT AddrStatus (statusDesc) VALUES (@statusValue)
  SELECT @statusId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END

-- copy from the input table to the output table, setting the correct status
INSERT empaddr_verified(empId, empalladdr, statusid)
SELECT empId, empaddr, @statusId FROM inputtable WHERE empId = @empid

GO
```

sure its only doing it one at a time, but at least it's easy :)
It will be very difficult to get any bulk savings when you have a 1-at-a-time API to work with.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a Bulk Copy Utility like [bcp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) or SSIS to do the data load. If you really want to code for it then use the [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class. This wont be as efficient as the first methods though.

[StackOverFlow: Bulk insert records into SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026204/bulk-insert-records-into-sql-server-database)

Comment: How can you use SQLBulkCopy if I have to reference other tables like  AddressStatuses before inserting into empaddr_verified table.

Comment: At the point of insert you need to have all the information available ready to be inserted in one go. In a separate process add the statuses first. Once they are added in, then add all you addresses separately?